# Retailers search with google maps API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to build a postcode checker where the user will put in a postcode and it they will be presented with a google map with their 3 nearest retailers. It will also need to zoom in to the point where it shows all the 3 results, unless there are only 1 or 2 results.
I have been given an excel document with the following information:

```
Company
Address line 1
Address Line2
Postcode
URL
Contact telephone number
```

If the user is then presented with a retailer on the map, they can then click on the icon, which will display a tooltip with the relevant information. Company name, url etc.

I’ve used the google maps API a couple of times but not done anything as advanced as this. I need to know how google maps will read the data in the excel document, will I need to convert it into an XML document, or would it need to be added into the database? 
Is the postcode enough for google maps to go off of? Or would I need to add the longitude and latitude?

I guess I would need google maps to workout which postcodes are closest to the ones that user has inputted to the search box, then to present the closest three.
It’s being built into a DRUPAL based site, and would be good if the results could be CMSable so the client can go in at any time and add new retailers.

Like I said it's not something i've built before, so really just looking for advice.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Business Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772283/google-maps-api-business-search)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135243/finding-towns-within-a-10-mile-radius-of-postcode-google-maps-api?rq=1

Comment: Just edit that to only show the top 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Google have a tutorial on how to do something similar, documentation can be found here - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Answer (score 0):

I have done this several times and im not claiming the following manner is the way to go.

I usually let the customer fill in the addresses in the CMS, and use an function to determine the long/lat based on the addresses to save the lat/long and the full adres.

After that i use jquery at the front to loop through the lat/longs to place markers on the map, by using an `setBounds` function which google map recognizes you can center the results. (Like you said zoom on the markers).

While looping through the markers you can append text to the markers.

The above is step 1.

Step 2:

You have to rebuild the map after you enter postcodes, for this i use ajax. I fire my info to an page which again converts my potscode to lat/long  and based on the lat/long i can do an select on the database and return the events to my map. After that Step 1 goes in action with new data.

Note: You have to gather some information which you can find on stackoverflow on how to combine these actions.